# COM interop and marshaling of VARIANT(VT_PTR)

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

We use a 3rd party COM object, one of which methods under certain conditions returns a `VARIANT` of `VT_PTR` type. That upsets the default .NET marshaler, which throws the following error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'InvalidVariant' : 'An invalid VARIANT was
>   detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed
>   object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected
>   exceptions, corruption or data loss.

Method signatures:

```
// (Unmanaged) IDL:
HRESULT getAttribute([in] BSTR strAttributeName, [retval, out] VARIANT* AttributeValue);

// C#:
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
object getAttribute([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string strAttributeName);
```

**Is there an elegant way to bypass such marshaler's behavior and obtain the underlying unmanaged pointer on the managed side?**

What I've considered/tried so far:

- A custom marshaler:

  ```
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, 
  MarshalTypeRef = typeof(IntPtrMarshaler))]
  object getAttribute([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string strAttributeName);
  ```

  I did implement `IntPtrMarshaler`, just to find the interop layer **crashing the process even before any of my `ICustomMarshaler` methods gets called**. Perhaps, the `VARIANT*` argument type is not compatible with custom marshalers.
- Rewrite (or clone) the C# interface definition with `getAttribute` method redefined (like below) and do all the marshaling for output `VARIANT` manually:

  ```
  void getAttribute(
      [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)],
      string strAttributeName, 
      IntPtr result);
  ```

  This doesn't seem nice (the interface itself has 30+ other methods). It'd also break existing, unrelated pieces of code which already make use of `getAttribute` without issues.
- Obtain an unmanaged method address of `getAttribute` from vtable (using `Marshal.GetComSlotForMethodInfo` etc), then do the manual invocation and marshaling against my own custom delegate type (using `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` etc).

  So far, I've taken this approach and it seem to work fine, but it feels as such an overkill for what should be a simple thing.

Am I missing some other feasible interop options for this scenario? Or, maybe there is a way to make `CustomMarshaler` work here?

Comment: Did you try returning a IntPtr ? There is some info also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.topointer?view=netframework-4.7.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.variantwrapper?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Is it a dual/IDispatch interface?

Comment: @SimonMourier, it's a dual interface indeed, so VT_PTR  is a non-compliant return value, but I still need it from this object.

Comment: @Marco, where specifically do you suggest to return an IntPtr at? If anywhere, I'd expect an IntPtr to raw VARIANT provided to me when my ICustomMarshaler is called, but it doesn't get to it.

Comment: Because it's a dual interface (they are tight to stricter rules), IMHO 1) won't work and I don't see how you're going to do 2), so if 3) works well, why not (you can add extension methods to interfaces it's a nice way to add syntactic sugar to use them). I don't see it as a "simple thing" at all, because the 3rd party side violates VARIANT/Automation rules. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237562.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier, I'm going to settle with 3). Disappointed I couldn't get it done with CustomMarshaler, there where it should have been a simple thing. Maybe it's a framework bug. Happy to provide a self-contained C#/C++ repro if you're interested to play with it.

Comment: I actually tried :-) but I'm ok to test your exact environment, in fact there's one important question: are you running in the same COM apartment (cause if there's marshaling, you're pretty much doomed, because what will crash is the universal marshaler, oleaut)?

Comment: @SimonMourier, same STA apartment. Will attach a sample when I get back to my laptop, thanks for hanging on with me on this one :)

Comment: I thought using IntPtr on the return type, but it seems like VARIANT of VT_PTR won't work at all. I guess you will need to write a c++ wrapper for the function and offer specific types to your c# and not VT_PTR.

Comment: If it's the same apartment, you could do something like this: https://pastebin.com/a8qLBi1m

Comment: @SimonMourier, interesting - tks! Worth posting as an answer. To compare, here's what I'm currently using: https://pastebin.com/0qdDDSzC. I like that it's x86/x64 agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is define a simple [VARIANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e305240e-9e11-4006-98cc-26f4932d2118(VS.85)) structure like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VARIANT
{
    public ushort vt;
    public ushort r0;
    public ushort r1;
    public ushort r2;
    public IntPtr ptr0;
    public IntPtr ptr1;
}
```

And the interface like this;

```
[Guid("39c16a44-d28a-4153-a2f9-08d70daa0e22"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface MyInterface
{
    VARIANT getAttributeAsVARIANT([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string strAttributeName);
}
```

Then, add an extension method somewhere in a static class like this, so the caller can have the same coding experience using MyInterface:

```
public static object getAttribute(this MyInterface o, string strAttributeName)
{
    return VariantSanitize(o.getAttributeAsVARIANT(strAttributeName));
}

private static object VariantSanitize(VARIANT variant)
{
    const int VT_PTR = 26;
    const int VT_I8 = 20;

    if (variant.vt == VT_PTR)
    {
        variant.vt = VT_I8;
    }

    var ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf<VARIANT>());
    try
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(variant, ptr, false);
        return Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(ptr);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
    }
}
```

This will do nothing for normal variants, but will just patch it for VT_PTR cases.

Note this only works if the caller and the callee are in the same COM apartement.

If they are not, you will get the DISP_E_BADVARTYPE error back because marshaling must be done, and by default, it will be done by the COM universal marshaler (OLEAUT) which only support [Automation compatible data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237562.aspx) (just like .NET).

In this case, theoratically, you could replace this marshaler by another one (at COM level, not at NET level), but that would mean to add some code on C++ side and possibly in the registry (proxy/stub, IMarshal, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

For my own future reference, here's how I ended up doing it, using the 3rd option mentioned in the question:

```
[ComImport, Guid("75A67021-058A-4E2A-8686-52181AAF600A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IInterface
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    object getAttribute([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string strAttributeName);
}

private delegate int IInterface_getAttribute(
    IntPtr pInterface,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string name,
    IntPtr result);

public static object getAttribute(this IInterface obj, string name)
{
    var ifaceType = typeof(IInterface);
    var ifaceMethodInfo = ((Func<string, object>)obj.getAttribute).Method;
    var slot = Marshal.GetComSlotForMethodInfo(ifaceMethodInfo);
    var ifacePtr = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(obj, ifaceType);
    try
    {
        var vtablePtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ifacePtr);
        var methodPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(vtablePtr, IntPtr.Size * slot);
        var methodWrapper = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<IInterface_getAttribute>(methodPtr);
        var resultVar = new VariantClass();
        var resultHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(resultVar, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            var pResultVar = resultHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            VariantInit(pResultVar);
            var hr = methodWrapper(ifacePtr, name, pResultVar);
            if (hr < 0)
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            if (resultVar.vt == VT_PTR)
            {
                return resultVar.ptr;
            }
            try
            {
                return Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(pResultVar);
            }
            finally
            {
                VariantClear(pResultVar);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            resultHandle.Free();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.Release(ifacePtr);
    }
}
```